# Can I reliably set a function pointer to NULL in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, gcc, g++

In P.J. Plauger's book, *The Standard C Library*, he warns about assigning a function pointer to NULL.

Specifically, he says this:

> The macro **NULL**  serves as an almost-universal null pointer constant. You use it as the value of a data-object pointer that should point to no data object declared (or allocated) in the program. As I mentioned on page 216, the macro can have any of the following definitions 0, 0L, or (void *)0.

> The last definition is compatible with any data object pointer. It is *not*, however, compatible with a function pointer. That means you cannot write

> `int (*pfun) (void) = NULL;    /* WRONG */`

> The translator may complain that the expression type is incompatible with the data object you wish to initialize.

He goes on to say that:

> ...There is no guarantee, however, that a pointer to void has the same *representation* as any other (non-character) pointer. It isn't even assignment compatible with function pointers. **That means that you can't write NULL as a universal null-pointer constant**. Nor can you safely use it as an argument expression in place of an arbitrary data-object pointer.

I have been assigning function pointers to `NULL` for quite some time without any problems, and I am wondering if it isn't portable.

Specifically:

`void (*test)() = NULL` => compiles fine with both gcc and g++

`void (*test)() = 0` => compiles fine with both gcc and g++

<strike>`void (*test)() = (void*)0` => produced an invalid conversion error in both gcc and g++</strike>

**EDIT: `void (*test)() = (void*)0`compiles fine in gcc, I was using a file with a .cpp extension...
Still, will it always compile, despite Plauger saying that assigning a function pointer to `NULL` is wrong?**

The part I don't understand is the definition of NULL in my stddef.h:

```
#if defined (_STDDEF_H) || defined (__need_NULL)
#undef NULL     /* in case <stdio.h> has defined it. */
#ifdef __GNUG__
#define NULL __null
#else   /* G++ */
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define NULL ((void *)0) // this line confuses me
#else   /* C++ */
#define NULL 0
#endif  /* C++ */
#endif  /* G++ */
#endif  /* NULL not defined and <stddef.h> or need NULL.  */
#undef  __need_NULL
```

This seems to be defining `NULL` to be 0 in C++ and ((void *)0) in C. Is it really, or is it being defined as __null?

If so, why does assigning to `NULL` work all the time, even though assigning to (void*)0,  according to Plauger, is "wrong"?**

I am interested in C89**

Comment: The `__null` definition is only in G++.

Comment: That's what I figured, thank you.

Comment: It's normal for `NULL` to be `((void *)0)` in C, and `0` in C++. Which part of that don't you understand?

Comment: @M.M The part where Plauger says that assigning NULL to a function pointer is wrong, specifically when it is defined as (void*)0.

Comment: One case where `NULL` by itself can't be safely used to denote a null pointer is an argument to a variadic function. For example, the POSIX `execl` function's last argument needs to be a null pointer, but it has to be written as `(char*)NULL` because the compiler doesn't know the expected type, so it can't generate the required conversion.

Comment: Some old compilers like the ones on solaris actually do give a warning for this type of assignment like `assignment mismatch: pointer to function(...) returning void "=" pointer to void`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 int (*pfun) (void) = NULL;
```

It is actually valid.

The C rules of assignment says that:

(Note that's an initialization here but the same type of constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply.)

> (C99, 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment p1 Constraints) "One of the following shall hold: [...] — the left operand is a pointer and the right is a null pointer constant;"

and

> (C99, 7.17p3) "The macros are NULL which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant;"

So assigning a null pointer constant to any pointer (object pointer, function pointer or `void *`) is allowed by C. Note that Plauger's book refers to C89 when he mentions Standard C but the wording of the assignment constraints are the same in C89.

Comment: That's a good point, but is it the same for C89? Sorry that I didn't make that obvious in my question. (ignore this question)

Comment: @rationalcoder in my last sentence I explicitly say it is the same in C89.

Comment: Wow, sorry for that. If it is the same, then is he just wrong to say that it is wrong, and it will always work for C89 compliant compilers?

Comment: @rationalcoder to me, saying that `pfun` declaration is *WRONG* is incorrect and IMHO the declaration is valid.

Comment: @rationalcoder by the way the c-faq seems to agree with that http://c-faq.com/null/fcnptr.html

Answer (score 11):

> `void (*test)() = (void*)0` => produced an invalid conversion error in both gcc and g++

GCC detects the language based on the file extension. Compiling a `.cc` file with GCC will invoke the C++ compiler, *not* the C compiler.

Try it with a C source file and you'll see this is accepted. As it should be, as it's allowed by the standard.

> If so, why does assigning to NULL work all the time, but assigning to (void*)0 not?

`NULL` isn' t allowed to be defined as `((void*)0)` in C++ mode. In C++ mode, it must be defined as either an integral constant with value 0, or as `nullptr`. Either can be converted to any function pointer type.

> Can I always reliably set a function pointer to NULL in C and C++?

Yes, in any conforming C or C++ implementation this will work.

Comment: do you have a reference for `GCC detects the language based on the file extension. Compiling a .cc file with GCC will invoke the C++ compiler, not the C compiler.`?

Comment: Ha! I didn't occur to me that I wasn't using different files, thanks!

Comment: @mch [GCC manual: Compiling C++ Programs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html): "GCC recognizes files with these names [.cc and others mentioned earlier] and compiles them as C++ programs even if you call the compiler the same way as for compiling C programs (usually with the name `gcc`)."

Comment: Why, then, does it work at all, when (void*) and void(*)() aren't directly assignable?

Comment: @rationalcoder The same way `void *p = 0;` is allowed even though `void *p = 1;` isn't: there's a special exception for null pointer constants.

Comment: @hvd Yes, but why would Plauger say it is wrong to assign NULL to a function pointer?

Comment: @rationalcoder I don't know. All versions of C to date allow `(void *)0` to be implicitly converted to any pointer type, even a function pointer type. All versions of C++ to date don't allow `NULL` to be defined as `((void *)0)`. The only reason I can think of is to deal with buggy implementations.

Comment: @rationalcoder: Looks like he made a mistake. It happens.